# PERL: Sorting Letters from A to Z

Tags: perl, file, sorting

I'm Trying to sort letters in a file from A to Z
for example: a A B d r g
sorted: A a B d g r

```
@ARGV == 2 or die "Usage: $0 infile outfile\n";
open $old,  '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
open $new, '>', $ARGV[1] or die $!;
@mass=<$old>;
@array=qw(@mass);
@sort=sort @array;
@mass1=sort {uc $a cmp uc $b} @sort;
print $new @mass1;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to sort letters or words? What exactly does your input file contain? Something like `a A B d r g`? If so does it contain more than one line?

Comment: I have a file with words and letters, so I have to sort them by alphabet

Comment: So `ba ab a` should turn out like `a ab ba`?

Comment: And you want uppercase sorted over lowercase? `a A b B` must yield `A a B b`? If so then Axeman's answer has that bit covered.

Comment: yes, by the way, "@array = map { split /\s+/} @mass;" im getting every word connected, i mean Spaces have been removed

Comment: See my last update. Use `join`, the inverse of `split` to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you intended to do with `qw`, but
suffice it to say that the contents of `@mass` will be never be used.

```
@array = qw(hello world);
```

Will cause `@array` to be defined to contain 2 *strings*, `hello` and `world`. It is just shorthand for:

```
@array = ('hello', 'world');
```

Which is why

```
@array=qw(@mass);
```

Evaluates to `('@mass')` - an array with the single literal string of 5 characters `@mass`.

Maybe that's what you're doing wrong. What if you try

```
@array = map { split /\s+/} @mass;
```

`@mass` is the list of lines. Each line has words or just letters, separated by space.
What that last line does is maps each line with `split /\s+/` - which will split each
line like `'ba ab a G'` into a *list* like `('ba', 'ab', 'a', 'G')` and `@array` will 
become a single list of words/letters.

Then it's a matter of how you want to sort them. See the other answer as well.

Oh, and remember to put back the spaces when you write out your file:

```
print $new (join " ", @mass1);
```

If you want each line to be sorted interdependently of the other, that's easy too:

```
$mass1 = join "\n", map { join " ", sort (split /\s+/) }  @mass
```

That reads, 'for every line in `@mass`, split on space, sort and join back again with space', and with the resulting array, join with `newline` to produce the output of the file.

Note that you can drop in `sort` with a comparator like `sort { $a cmp $b }` etc.

If your file is too big, then looping is maybe prudent:

```
for my $mass (<$old>) {
    my $sorted_line = join " ", sort (split /\s+/, $mass);
    print $new "$sorted_line\n";
}
```

Comment: Noticed that it's deleting all lines and writing everything in 1 line

Comment: You've got to be as specific as you can. If you have words in multiple lines, and want them sorted, then you either: (a) want each line to be sorted independently of the other; OR (b) want all words in the whole file to be sorted as one set.  Not that (b) implies that you will get an output without lines! So I take it you want (a) not (b)?

Comment: I'd like to sort whole file, so maybe it can be done with looping the file?

Comment: I've noticed the changes you have made, now it works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you understand the the standard text ordering is ASCII-based. So because all uppercase proceed all lowercase, the same is true of your input. Therefore, you order for a straight `sort` would be `( 'A', 'B', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'r' )`.

You want to *double* compare the two strings. In this case, you're going to need to pass a routine to sort.

```
@sort= sort { lc $a cmp lc $b or $a cmp $b } @array;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the correct LOCALE to use, so that the order used by all functions (sort, etc) are using the correct locale and sort accordingly to it.

See [this page showing most of the variables defining locales](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html), and look for LANG and LC_ALL. and LC_COLLATE (I have to admit I'm not exactly sure which is used when. LC_ALL is supposed to take precedence over the others, so it's the one you can change to have all LC_* values set... Please test, ymmv)

I believe you probably need to use one of the unicode locales. Ascii won't do what you want, as CAPS are before regular letters in ascii.

To find out which locales you can use: `locale -a`

To see which locales you are currently set to : `locale` (user and system-wide values are possible)

You probably need something containing "utf-8" to have the order you seek

Then : (if for example en_US.UTF-8 is available):

just before using it in the sort, define locales you want to sort with:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

(or whatever the value you need it to be set at, and is available as shown by "locale -a")

(save/restore their previous values around the invocation if you need to)

In shell, you probably better want to ass "export" to those variables you redefine, to ensure subshells use the new value too (like: `something | sort` : in bash, `sort` will be in a subshell, therefore using the default value of LC_*, or using the exported value if you exported it!)